# Как я могу получить ID элемента?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, google-chrome, junit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо получить ID элемента в поисковике гугл, но почему-то они не привязывают id к своим элементам.
Мне это нужно для написания юнит теста, чтоб дать запрос в поисковик.

Answer (score 1):

У указанного Вами input нету id, есть только class="gLFyf gsfi".
Вам нужно сделать привязку к class, а не к id и заработает ваш unit-test.

Comment: WebElement inputField = webDriver.findElement(By.className("gLFyf gsfi")); так получается надо искать ?

Comment: да, по логике верно (дальше копайте уже саму документацию Selenium-а, если не сработает данный код).

Вот хорошая статья (схожа с тем что вы пытаетесь сделать): https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/how-to-locate-element-by-class-name-locator/